# How to read the matrix values after "reshape"

Tags: matlab, vector, matrix, reshape

Say for instance that I have the following `vector`:

```
x=[1 2 3 4];
```

Here, the vector is read as follows:

```
x1=1
x2=2
x3=3
x4=4
```

Is that correct?

Now, if I do the following:

```
y = reshape(x,2,2);
```

I will get the following `matrix`:

```
1  3
2  4
```

In this case, what will be the values of `y1, y2, y3, and y4`? Will they be as in the `vector` above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Matlab stores data in [column-major order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order#Column-major_order).

For lots more details and examples of Matlab indexing, see [Matrix Indexing in MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/Matrix-Indexing-in-MATLAB/matrix.html).

Comment: Also, if you are the kind of guy that likes video tutorials, Doug's blog is a great source. Check this link (http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2007/08/31/matlab-basics-video-row-and-column-indexing/) for a video regarding row-column indexing.